# Use relative references

Tags: excel, vba, performance, loops, simplify

Being new to VBA I would love some inputs to this code, to improve the speed of it... It doesn't feel so "VBA"-ish currently; however the "result" of the code correct...

```
Sub Rigtig()

Set Marketshare = Sheets("Output").Range("p40:p50")
'Select.
Sheets("Output").Select
    Cells(38, 17).Copy
Sheets("Input").Select
   Cells(33, 28).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Output").Select
Marketshare.Cells(1, 1).Copy
Sheets("Input").Select
    Cells(23, 28).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets("Output").Select
    Cells(40, 17).Copy
    Cells(40, 17).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Marketshare.Cells(2, 1).Copy
Sheets("Input").Select
    Cells(23, 28).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets("Output").Select
    Cells(41, 17).Copy
    Cells(41, 17).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Marketshare.Cells(3, 1).Copy
Sheets("Input").Select
    Cells(23, 28).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


Sheets("Output").Select
    Cells(38, 18).Copy
Sheets("Input").Select
   Cells(33, 28).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Output").Select
Marketshare.Cells(1, 1).Copy
Sheets("Input").Select
    Cells(23, 28).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets("Output").Select
    Cells(40, 18).Copy
    Cells(40, 18).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Output").Select
    Cells(38, 19).Copy
Sheets("Input").Select
   Cells(33, 28).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Output").Select
Marketshare.Cells(1, 1).Copy
Sheets("Input").Select
    Cells(23, 28).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets("Output").Select
    Cells(40, 19).Copy
    Cells(40, 19).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Marketshare.Cells(2, 1).Copy
Sheets("Input").Select
    Cells(23, 28).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

I would like to do the same "copy paste" approx 10 times in rows, and then change the column.

Thanks in advance

Best

Valdemar

Comment: Rather than doing a load of Copy and Pasting, you should update cell values directly... Also avoid using select wherever possible - for example the first copy and past can be written `Sheets("Output").Cells(33, 28).Value = Sheets("Output").Cells(38, 17).Value` or even `With Sheets("Output")    .Cells(33, 28).Value = .Cells(38, 17).Value    End With`

Comment: It's a good idea not to use "Copy/Paste" within a VBA script: just imagine the following: you copy something on the clipboard, you launch a program, and your copy is lost (you can't paste anymore). If you don't use "Copy/Paste" in a script, the clipboard is not touched and you can still paste what you have copied before.

Comment: Hi Dominique, thanks, i'll keep that in mind. 

Do you have any suggestions as to how I can create a loop instead of repeating the code just replacing the row number?

I've tried to explain my next step in a new answer

Answer (score 1):

As @Glitch_Doctor said - if it's just the values you're after you can do this "this cell = that cell" rather than copy/paste.

To shorten your code and make it a bit more "VBA"-ish you could put your cell reference pairs into an array and step through the array:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim vAddresses As Variant
    Dim vRef As Variant

    vAddresses = Array( _
        Array("Q38", "AB33"), _
        Array("A1", "AB23"))

    For Each vRef In vAddresses
        Worksheets("Input").Range(vRef(1)) = Worksheets("Output").Range(vRef(0))
    Next vRef

End Sub
```

You could also use a [With...End With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) block so you don't have to use the sheet name each time:

```
Sub Test1()

    With Worksheets("Output")
        Worksheets("Input").Cells(33, 28) = .Cells(38, 17)
    End With

End Sub
```

If you want to copy everything (formula, formatting) then use Copy & paste in a single line:

```
Sub Test2()

    With Worksheets("Output")
        Worksheets("Input").Cells(33, 28).Copy Destination:=.Cells(38, 17)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Darren, thanks for your response.
What im trying to do, is to get VBA to insert a value in a cell which then calculates a value for me. Then I want to "save" this value as a number, since the next value that gets calculated is with the same formula (same input cell but new input value). So in order to get the new value without changing the old value I guess this is necessary?

So what i'm basically trying to get i a matrix, where it fills the rows first  (with the corresponding input) and then change column input and do it all over again...

Comment: Not sure if this makes sense?

I tried your code but it does not return the values I wanted :)

Comment: The code you posted doesn't insert any values into cells - only the copying/pasting way.  My first block of code replicates that - copies the value from `AB33` to `Q38` and so on.  Other than that how are values inserted?

Comment: Hmm.. Im stil  not quite sure what your first block does... Not really sure about the cell references, are they supposed to copy the same as mine?

Comment: Yes, The `For...Each` line looks at each array of two addresses in turn and moves the values from one cell reference to the other.  You could also replicate your code using `Sheets("Input").Cells(33, 28) = Sheets("Output").Cells(38, 17)` which replaces the first copy/paste block in your code.

Comment: Okay - I think i get some of your first Block now. But how do you get it to insert the next variable instead of the first? 
And how do you replace the first value as a formula to a value?

Comment: The [For...Each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement) line steps through the array.   `vAddresses` is an array of arrays - i.e. it's an array that contains arrays. `vRef` steps through each of those - so the first loop looks at `("Q38", "AB33")`, the second at `("A1", "AB23")`.  An array is 0 based, so `Q38` is element 0, `AB33` is element 1.  So `Range(vRef(0))` is looking at the first figure in the array as a range - `Q38`.

Comment: When you say "replace the first value as a formula to a value" - that will happen with `Cells(33,28) = Cells(38,17)`.  It makes the value of cell(33,28) equal to the value in cell(38,17).  The formula isn't copied across.  If that's not what you mean then I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't seem to get the loop working, its like it only enters 1 value and then stops?

Also, what I want to do with the calculated value in the matrix table, is to "insert" as a value..

Comment: Im trying to create a matrix with unique values in each cell, depending on the two input axis, if this makes sense?

Comment: No idea why it stops at one loop.  If I create two sheets - `Input` and `Output` and place the code in a normal module, place text in cell `A1` & `Q38` of the `Output` sheet it copies both values over to column `AB` of the `Input` sheet.  Your last comment does make sense - but not when I look at the code you're using.  It just copies values from `Output` sheet to the `Input`, nothing to do with uniques or a specific matrix of values.

Comment: So the value that it takes from the output sheet into input, changes the values in the output's matrix. So the values in the matrix are dependent on the values in the input sheet

Comment: Oh, and yes; to your comment: I would like it to repeat the action of copying A1, A2, A3, A4 etc whilst keeping Q38 values.. Does this make sense?

Comment: Basically I wish to create a Datatable (If you're familiar with these from Excel). But I think the output i wish to have in the datatable is dependent on too many variables for the datatable to work properly..

Comment: I'm familiar with Data Tables (as in define a table from the Insert ribbon - or do you mean from the _What If Analysis_ which I'm not so familiar with) but your question and subsequent comments have left me thoroughly confused as to what the problem is.

Comment: The Latter - the What if data table :) 

So; I wish to create a matrix table, where the values in the table are dependent on the values in the "axis' "; so for a column the row input changes 10 times, with the same column input, then for the next column a new input is made and then same procedure with 10 inputs for the rows. 
Hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

So I want it to be something like this:

```
    Sub Test()

    Dim vAddresses As Variant
    Dim vRef As Variant

    vAddresses = Array( _
        Array("Q38", "AB33"), _
        Array("P40", "AB23"))

For Each vRef In vAddresses
        Worksheets("Input").Range(vRef(1)) = Worksheets("Output").Range(vRef(0))
    Next vRef

Sheets("Output").Cells(40, 17).Value = Sheets("Output").Cells(40, 17).Value

 vAddresses = Array( _
        Array("Q38", "AB33"), _
        Array("P41", "AB23"))
For Each vRef In vAddresses
        Worksheets("Input").Range(vRef(1)) = Worksheets("Output").Range(vRef(0))
    Next vRef

Sheets("Output").Cells(41, 17).Value = Sheets("Output").Cells(41, 17).Value
```

Does this makes sense?

So repeating it 10x down in rows, and then move 1 column left and do it again.

Hope you get my point, and thanks :)

/Valdemar

Comment: So, the next "step" here is to make this a "loop" so I wont have to repeat the code 10 times, changing P41 -> P42 and so forth; and next changing Q38 -> R38 (and fx Cells(41, 18)

Comment: Please don't post questions as answers. Post a new question if you are moving beyond the scope of your original.